Do not put wlan inteface down in case of reauthenticate
It seems that the kernel (?) puts the interface down and then up when wlan interface connected to some AP reconnect from one BSSID to another. Is it possible to prevent kernel from doing it? So interface stays up during this process?

No, you can't be connected to 2 wireless networks at the same time.

@eyoung100 Yes you can: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/iw/vif

Well thank you @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica, I learned something new today.
